# MediaWiki custom authentication requirements

Tags: php, authentication, mediawiki

I am trying to create a wiki for which viewing and editing the wiki must be restricted to two small groups of users.

Since it is a university society, we already have an external authentication system, run by the university, and I have already implemented that such that `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` is used for authentication. This, however, allows access to anyone in the university. I want to create two small subsets of users 'exec' and 'steering_committee' who are able to view and edit the wiki.

I have been playing with the authentication plugin I have been using, but when I try and return `false` from `authenticate($user, $pwd)` I don't see any access forbidden warnings.

So my question is, what is the best way to go about creating this sort of authentication? I would like to be able to add data that is fetched about users (exec position, former exec positions) which are contained in two tables `wiki_exec` and `wiki_user_former_positions` so that it is available to the wiki.

Comment: Ok so I have used groups do restrict access, but now I want to be able to have either this remote_user login (which can be done via an htaccess directive and an apache module) and also via some user accounts for those people who have left the university and can no longer gain access via the university auth system.

Is there a way to alter the login form to reflect both methods?

Comment: Did you take a look at all the [MediaWiki authentication extensions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:User_identity_extensions)?

Comment: @Christian no I hadn't, thanks for linking me here. I had been digging through the source for mediawiki and the api documentation with little luck. I'm not very familiar with the platform. I will take a look, the  [MultiAuth Plugin](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MultiAuthPlugin) looks especially good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way looks like using the MultiAuth plugin, although it is really not particularly easy to extend (although perhaps one has to be more familiar with MedaiWiki).

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MultiAuthPlugin

(thanks @Christian for pointing me in the right direction)